# From/To vs. To/From for shuttle app?

Tags: website-design, user-expectation

At where I work (a university) we have shuttles. Recently, our internal web page was redesigned and shuttle hours are now currently displayed here along with other information. My question relates to the hours and what order they should be displayed.

Is it better to put the campus to city hours first on a desktop, or vice-versa? What about on a mobile device? I've got no UX education, but I feel like campus to city is the best option. Here is a screenshot of it:

[image: shuttle hours]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you personally based on Campus? I'd consider whether most of the shuttle users live on campus and would be mainly interested in going to the city, or the other way around. You might also want to consider monitoring usage of the system after a few months and changing your approach if the data suggests your initial assumption was wrong.

Comment: I don't live on the campus, but this still concerns me.

Comment: I mean I don't live, but I work there

Answer (score 1):

There are some things that are not 100% clear here.

In the first place, I thought it was a journey FROM a place (on the right) TO another place (on the left) - in this case the change of order was just obvious, because by change it you would achieve more natural representation of the real life scenario (left-to-rigt = start-to-destination).

But it's not the case (although the misunderstanding shows that the concept needs to be polished). The next thought, having read what you wrote, brings another confusion:

- are these in fact **departures** and **arrivals** for one specific stop? Or:
- are these **departures from campus** and **departures from the city** put side by side?

I'm not sure about it, but there is not enough information for the user in both cases. In the first case, I would suggest going for "Arrivals" and "Departures" naming, which are obvious and will make user anchor on this being a timetable for a specific stop.

If it is the second case, though, I suggest being more descriptive, saying: "Departures from Campus" and "Departures from the City".

Another confusion users may face is that due to proximity of the entries users may link one to another: "Aha, so this shuttle starts from this stop at 10:30 and arrives at that stop at 13:00." - which may be incorrect. To solve this, you may split it into two views with a selector at the top of the list.

Comment: The first column is to the city, the second is from.

Comment: Yes, but which case: 1. Left: DEPARTURE from campus to the city, Right: DEPARTURE from the city or case 2: Left: DEPARTURE from campus to the city, Right: ARRIVAL at the campus.

Comment: Left: Departure to the city, and right: departure from the city.

Comment: But you see - it needs clarification. Thus, you could at least add proper, descriptive headings: "Departures from campus to the city" and "Departures from the city to campus". Or at least "Campus to city" and "City to campus". You may also consider splitting it into two views to avoid confusion. I believe Kadıköy is a name of a specific stop on the way, and there will be many of them - is it like this? In this case, why not showing all the route top-to-bottom, starting with campus and ending with city in one direction, and the other way around in the other case? It would be self-explanatory.

Comment: There are 2 stops; Kadikoy is the 2nd and last.

Answer (score 0):

The order by time makes sense here. It's just the labeling that is confusing.
A simple change can make it a lot clearer:

[image: Changed only the label]

Or

[image]

If the two cities are always the same you can remove the second:

[image]